# How to locally disable optimization

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization, jit

I faced with strange problem. My app has next code, that execute on startup:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
{
    // App.container - UnityContainer
    var dvcc = new MyClientCore(new MySorter());
    App.container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ClientCore), dvcc);
    App.container.RegisterInstance(typeof(MyClientCore), dvcc);

    this.dataProvider = new MyProvider();
    this.dataProvider.Configure(App.container);
    App.container.RegisterInstance(typeof(Provider), this.dataProvider);
    App.container.RegisterInstance(typeof(MyProvider), this.dataProvider);

    // Create view models and register them in container
    this.RegisterViewModels();

    // Command - singleton, that resolved in ctor view models, 
    // that registered in RegisterViewModels();
    Command.Instance.InitCommands();

    // Create and configure shell 
}
```

When app execute in debug configuration there are no problem. Also when app execute in release configuration in visual studio.
But when I try to start app directly I get TypeInitializationException in Command ctor because of resolution of the dependency registered in  dataProvider.Configure method.

I thought that cause in JIT optimization, and code may be execute like

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
{
    Command.Instance.InitCommands();
    // other method body
}
```

I found solution for that - mark RegisterTypes method atribute [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)].

But maybe exist better method to fix it? Also I will be gratiful for link, when that situation explained with simple words.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why do you think it's the JIT optimization? "When app execute in debug configuration there are no problem. Also when app execute in release configuration in visual studio." The Release configuration has optimizations enabled, even running under Visual Studio, so you've already shown it works with optimizations enabled. You don't provide enough code to reproduce the error, so others can't investigate it. [mcve]

Comment: Solution contains from several project and full example will be large. I think that, because problem was solved after add [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]